# Import raster layer to Potree viewer

Tags: raster, 3d, import, three-js, potree

I need to import a raster layer into Potree viewer. I don't need to extrude raster by pointcloud. I only need a raster base layer. There is examples with Cesium, but it is too heavy for my task. Maybe I can convert Raster to .ply and import it to Potree?